# Error 'APILifeCycle' WSO2 Api Manager - Quantity of Apis Distorced Showed at publisher page

Tags: kubernetes, wso2, wso2-api-manager

First I would like of congratulations all people that help us here!!

I am a problem with wso2 APIM version 4.1.0 deployed at kubernetes Cluster 1.25.4.

We are using Oracle 19c as Database.

When some analysts connect at Publisher page,to create apis, appear many apis at page and error http error 500 dont be possible to create the api.
Obs: Apis count only increase at publisher page but it not appear at dev portal.

At logs of control plane, is showed:

````
ERROR - GovernanceArtifactImpl Error in associating lifecycle for the artifact. id: 44879109-49c7-484f-8b00-44e9bc129f48, path: /apimgt/applicationdata/provider/admin/TestAPICallback/1.0.0/api.
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Couldn't find aspectName 'APILifeCycle'
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.associateAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2485) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.associateAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:499) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.associateAspectInternal(UserRegistry.java:1913) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$3800(UserRegistry.java:73) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$39.run(UserRegistry.java:1885) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$39.run(UserRegistry.java:1882) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.associateAspect(UserRegistry.java:1882) ~[org.wso2.carbon.registry.core_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.attachLifecycle(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:383) ~[org.wso2.carbon.governance.api_4.8.28.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.persistence.RegistryPersistenceImpl.addAPI(RegistryPersistenceImpl.java:197) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.persistence_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI_aroundBody30(APIProviderImpl.java:702) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:654) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI_aroundBody0(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:77) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:76) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.importOpenAPIDefinition(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:4843) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.importOpenAPIDefinition(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:3253) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.ApisApi.importOpenAPIDefinition(ApisApi.java:1378) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217) ~[?:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:101) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:146) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:58) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper Error while persisting API```

Thanks for help us
````

Comment: Do you have multi-tenancy configured?

Comment: No. Thanks Lakshitha for comment!!

Comment: We dont go use multi-tenancy at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to the Carbon Console.
2. Go to Extensions -> Configure -> LifeCycles . You should have at least 2: APILifeCycle and ServiceLifeCycle

If you don't have any Lifecycle:

1. Download the wso2am ZIP file from https://wso2.com/api-manager/
2. Unzip the downloaded file, in <WSO2_FOLDER>/repository/resources/lifecycles you will find 2 xml files (APILifeCycle.xml and ServiceLifeCycle.xml).
3. In the carbon console go again to Extensions -> Configure -> Lifecycles.
4. Add both Lifecycles by clicking on "Add new Lifecycle".

Normally these Lifecycles are created on the first start of WSO2 APIM.